# How to save a matrix indexes

Tags: c, arrays, matrix

Im practicing c and I have some trouble with this code :
I want to make a movie theatre ticket program.
The programs is getting a specific number evertime, and its seeking for the first free seats, if there are none it suppose to print a massage.
The seats must be attached to each other and in the same row.
The indexes of the seats need to be printed as well as mark as taken..
Im marking 1 as taken and 0 as untaken.
I need your help with how to save the indexes everytime.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


main()
{
    int i, j;
    int Freeseats = 0;
    int arr[10][20]= {{0}};

    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<20; j++)
        {
            printf("%d", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    while(1)
    {

        int num, n=0;
        scanf("%d",&num);
        for(i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            for(j=0; j<20; j++)
            {
                if(arr[i][j] == 0 && Freeseats < num)
                {
                    Freeseats++;

                }
                else{
                    Freeseats = 0;
                }
                if(Freeseats == num)
                {

                }
            }

        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. To "save" something in a program you just assign it to one or more variables.

Comment: Each time the Freeseats variable is increasing, I want to save that exact index, and each time Freeseats is getting 0, I want to delete these indexes. like a temp variable, but I cant figure it out how to do it in that particular case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your approach is wrong. You don't need to save any indexes.

Your task is to find a row where there is N consecutive free seats. So you need an extra loop where you count the number of consecutive free seats.

Something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SEATS_PER_ROW 20
#define ROWS 10

main()
{
    int i, j, k, max;
    int arr[ROWS][SEATS_PER_ROW]= {{0}};

    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<20; j++)
        {
            printf("%d", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    while(1)
    {
        printf("Please enter the number of seats needed\n");

        int num, n=0;
        if (1 != scanf("%d",&num))
        {
            printf("Illegal input - stop program\n");
            break;
        }
        printf("Searching for %d seats\n", num);
        if (num > SEATS_PER_ROW)
        {
            printf("We don't have that many seats in a single row\n");
            continue;
        }

        int found = 0;
        for (i=0; i<10 && found != 1; i++)
        {
            found = 0;
            for (j=0; j<(20-num+1) && found != 1; j++)
            {
                found = 0;
                // Check for num consecutive free seats starting at i, j
                for (k=0; k<num; k++)
                {
                    if(arr[i][j+k] != 0)
                    {
                        // Can't sit here
                        found = -1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (found == 0)
                {
                    // We found a place - starting at i, j
                    // Mark them as used
                    found = 1;
                    printf("Seats assinged in row %d : seat %d to %d\n", i, j, j+num-1);
                    for(k=0; k<num; k++)
                    {
                        arr[i][j+k] = 1;
                    }

                    // Debug print
                    //for(i=0; i<10; i++)
                    //{
                    //    for(j=0; j<20; j++)
                    //    {
                    //        printf("%d", arr[i][j]);
                    //    }
                    //    printf("\n");
                    //}

                }
            }

        }
        if (found != 1)
        {
            printf("So many seats are not available\n");
        }
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

With input:

```
10
15
2
6
20
3
21
9
```

The output is:

```
Please enter the number of seats needed
Searching for 10 seats
Seats assinged in row 0 : seat 0 to 9
Please enter the number of seats needed
Searching for 15 seats
Seats assinged in row 1 : seat 0 to 14
Please enter the number of seats needed
Searching for 2 seats
Seats assinged in row 0 : seat 10 to 11
Please enter the number of seats needed
Searching for 6 seats
Seats assinged in row 0 : seat 12 to 17
Please enter the number of seats needed
Searching for 20 seats
Seats assinged in row 2 : seat 0 to 19
Please enter the number of seats needed
Searching for 3 seats
Seats assinged in row 1 : seat 15 to 17
Please enter the number of seats needed
Searching for 21 seats
We don't have that many seats in a single row
Please enter the number of seats needed
Searching for 9 seats
Seats assinged in row 3 : seat 0 to 8
Please enter the number of seats needed
Searching for 15 seats
Seats assinged in row 4 : seat 0 to 14
```

See it at https://ideone.com/36zjuC

Comment: Thanks ! I just compiled your code and it doesnt work. Only the first number I enter gets his seats, but the rest not matter what number it is doesnt get it at all. Plus the program doesnt let me know what seats are given.

Comment: @Natezone - ups, there was a mistake - answer updated